# Extending Calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I wanted to add more methods to the Calendar from java.util.Calendar, but I'm having trouble using the getInstance method.

If I have an object like:
`public class DateObject extends Calendar{ // other methods here }`

And I do `DateObject mon = DateObject.getInstance();`
The code does not work. Even if I replace it with Calendar.getInstance(), I can't convert a Calendar to my DateObject.

How do I make my DateObject use getInstance()?

Comment: DateObject is also a poor name given the existance of Date as a class already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getInstance()` is a static method on `Calendar`. You cannot override static methods. You will need to provide your own method.

But I would question the design of extending Calendar. You will almost certainly be better served by having your class wrap a Calendar rather than extend it. In particular, changing your calendar implementation will become very, very difficult.

Consider also, that the Calendar API is very broken in a number of respects, so perpetuating it would be a crime against baby kittens.

Have you considered an alternative date/time/calendar library which might already contain the functionality you want? For example [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Or, better yet, finding a library like Joda that will do whatever additional operations you seem to think are necessary.  A design that extends Calendar is almost certainly headed in a bad direction.

Answer (score 1):

getInstance() is a static/class method.  You can't.  What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subclass of Calendar doe not mean that the existing static `getInstance()` method in Calendar will magically know

One solution is to add a method or methods with a signature like:

```
public static DateObject getInstance(...);
```

to the DateObject class, and implement it to create DateObject instances as required.

Another possibility is to look at how the existing `getInstance()` factory method works, and figure out how to get it to create one of your DateObject instances.

Also, pay attention to the answers that suggest that extending Calendar is a bad idea.