# Extend java.util.calendar class

Tags: java, calendar

I want to extend the java.util.Calendar class in order to add some extra functionality:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
abstract class ExtendedCalendar extends Calendar {
    public static ExtendedCalendar getInstance()
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        return (ExtendedCalendar)c;
    }
}
```

I always get this exception, because Calendar.getInstance returns an GregorianCalendar:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to ExtendedCalendar
```

But how is it possible that a Cast of GregorianCalendar to Calendar is working?

```
Calendar calendar = (Calendar)c;
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: You could extend GregorianCalendar instead. Or provide a static utility class ccontaining the extra methods.

Answer (score 4):

`Calendar.getInstance()` is a static factory method that event does not allow any customizations or injections. It returns instance of concrete calendar. In most cases it is `GregorianCalendar`. It can be also `BuddhistCalendar` or `JapaneseImperialCalendar` depending on your locale.

If you want to create instance of your calendar just do it by direct call of your constructor: `new ExtendedCalendar()`.

BTW IMHO you do not really have to extend `GregorianCalendar`. Extending functionality is not limited to extending class. Create your own class that *uses* other calendar in its calculations instead of extending it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how polymorphism works.
Both `GregorianCalendar` and `ExtendedCalendar` are subclasses of `Calendar`. That means that both of them are also of type `Calendar`. However, a `GregorianCalendar` is not of type `ExtendedCalendar`

You can try to extend the `GregorianCalendar` if it is possible. Otherwise, you cannot cast from a subclass of `Calendar` to another subclass of `Calendar`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `Calendar` is an abstract class and `GergorianCalendar` is the current implementation of it.

So, I think your `ExtendedCalendar` class shouldn't be abstract.

You can extend `Calendar` with a normal class and add your functions. You will just need then to define your own attributes and methods. What you did is a good beginning.
You can also extend `GregorianCalendar`.

And you will have access to both the method of the implemented interface and your own.

Comment: Ah okay, so what is the best approach to extend the Calendar with some extra functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you [Extending Calendar in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756065/extending-calendar-in-java)
.Its a crime to extend calendar class which is already been ignored by many experts